# Uneven line spacing in tocloft for Devanagari

Tags: spacing, tocloft, devanagari

I have the following code. I am using LuaLaTex compiler with TeXLive version 2020.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\babelprovide[mapdigits,main]{hindi}
\defaultfontfeatures{Renderer=Harfbuzz,Script=Devanagari}
\babelfont{rm}{Noto Serif Devanagari}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\bfseries\Large}
\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\bfseries\Large}
\renewcommand\hindicontentsname{अनुक्रमणिका}
\renewcommand\hindichaptername{अध्याय}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{अरुणाचल प्रदेश}
\chapter{असम}
\chapter{आंध्र प्रदेश}
\chapter{उत्तरप्रदेश}
\chapter{उत्तराखंड}
\chapter{ओडिशा}
\chapter{कर्नाटक}
\chapter{केरल}
\chapter{गुजरात}
\chapter{गोवा}
\end{document}
```

This produces the below TOC. The line spacing in TOC chapter entries is uneven. I have tried several ideas but nothing worked.

[image]

Comment: you need a larger baselineskip, e.g. \linespread{1.3}